# Yes/No program using while loop in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user whether they would like to continue to the next calculation. For some reasons whenever I enter y or Y, the program ends. However, if I use only one condition inside the if statement(without '||'sign), the code works fine. I just want to make sure that the user can enter both upper and lower case.

What's wrong with the code? Is there a better way to do this?

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)"<<endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 'Y'|| choice =='y'){
        return true;
        }else if(choice =='N'||choice =='n'){
        return false;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code and examine what happens for different user input.

Comment: And.. What do you expect to happen, when the code reaches `return` statement (in your example)? Which leads me to the following question: is this your real code?

Comment: What do you expect `return true;` to accomplish?

Comment: Why are you using `return` statements?

Comment: How can your code even work "fine" without the "||".... ,read below

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement ends a function, in this case, this is the main, so it ends your program, whatever value you're returning.
If you only want to get out of your loop you have two solutions:
Use a boolean:

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    bool run = true; //@stefaanv
    while(run)
    {
        // Make your calculation
        cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)"<<endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice =='N'||choice =='n'){
            run = false;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Use `break` to exit your loop:

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    while(true)
    {
        // Make your calculation
        cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)"<<endl;
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice =='N'||choice =='n'){
            break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

But both these solution will consider any character entered exept N/n as "continue", if you want to avoid this:

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    bool run = true;
    while(run)
    {
        // Make your calculation
        do{
            cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)"<<endl;
            cin >> choice;
            choice = tolower(choice);//Put your letter to its lower case
        }while (choice != 'n' && choice != 'y')
        if(choice =='n'){
            run = false;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small warning: continue is a keyword in C and C++, avoid using keywords as variables.

Comment: @stefaanv Didn't know, editing...

Comment: @Treycos Thanks man, I tried your all your solutions. One thing, for the third solution using the tolower(choice), when I entered 'N'(uppercase), the program still continues for some reason, lowercase is fine. Also the program will continue if the user enters any key other than n.

Comment: I fixed the last solution, sorry

Answer (score 1):

> For some reasons whenever I enter y or Y, the program ends

The `return` statement is used to return control(and sometimes an optional value), to a functions caller. When return is used inside the called function, the function is terminated. From cppreference.com:

> [return] **terminates [the] current function and returns [a] specified value to the caller function**.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

You may be under the impression that the statement `return true` inside your while-loop is returning the Boolean value of true to your while condition. It is not.

---

If your end goal is to create a yes/no style program that ends when the user enters "No/no", then you can to make use of the `continue` and `break` statements, or use a `do/while` loop.

---

### Using `continue` and `break`

The `continue` statement is used to immediately skip to the next iteration of a loop, for or while, terminating the current iteration. From cppreference.com:

> **Causes the remaining portion of the enclosing for, range-for, while or do-while loop body to be skipped**.
>   Used when it is otherwise awkward to ignore the remaining portion of the loop using conditional statements.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The `break` statement is somewhat similar to `continue`, but instead of breaking the current iteration and skipping to the next one, it immediately breaks the entire program out of the while loop returning control to the outer-scope. From cppreference.com:

> **Causes the enclosing for, range-for, while or do-while loop or switch statement to terminate.**
>   Used when it is otherwise awkward to terminate the loop using the condition expression and conditional statements.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

After examining the information above, you can modify your program to make use of `continue` and `break`, instead of `return`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // This is for demonstration purposes ONLY
// never use this statement in your actual program. prefix cout and
// cin with std::

int main()
{
    char choice;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculations?(Y/N)"<<endl;
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 'Y'|| choice =='y'){
            continue; // instead of returning, skip to the next iteration
            // and ask again
        }else if(choice =='N'||choice =='n'){
            break; // return could be used here to break the while loop and 
            // terminate the program. But be explicit and use a statement specifically  
            // made for breaking out of loops
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

### Using a `do/while` loop

While the method above would work, I recommend using  my second option-- a `do/while` loop. The `do/while` has the advantage o being shorter, and not having to make use of any kind of major control flow. From cppreference:

> Executes a statement repeatedly, until the value of expression becomes false. The test takes place after each iteration.

If needed you could even add error checking to validate a users input:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // This is for demonstration purposes ONLY
// never use this statement in your actual program. prefix cout and
// cin with std::

int main()
{
    char choice;
    do { // do everything in the do block while...

        cout <<"Would you like to perform other calculations?(Y/N)"<< endl;

        cin >> choice;

        if (choice != 'Y' and choice != 'y' and choice != 'N' and choice != 'n') // if needed add input 
            cout << choice << " is not a valid option. Try agian" << endl; // validation

    } while (choice !='N' && choice !='n'); // the user input does not equal 'N'andr 'n'

return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Would you like to perform other calculations?(Y/N)
 y
Would you like to perform other calculations?(Y/N)
 Y
Would you like to perform other calculations?(Y/N)
 n
```

### References and Resources

- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)
- [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/)

Comment: Yeah it works fine, I combined it with data validation as well, so whenever the user input anything else it will loop back to the cout stage.

Comment: @HorseyPotato glad to here it is working for you.

Comment: Well answered, sir, eat an upvote and swallow!

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote some code and it works like a charm using "goto".
The code also included data validation as well. Many thanks to @Treycos.

```
int main()
{
char choice ='Y';
bool valid = true;
//some calculation
        here:
        int x =1+1;
        cout<<x<<endl;
    while(valid){
            cout<<"Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)"<<endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if(choice =='N' || choice =='n'){
                break;
        }
            if(choice =='Y'||choice =='y'){
                goto here;
        }
         else if(choice != 'N'&& choice != 'n'&&choice != 'Y'&&choice != 'y'){
                cout<<"Invalid input."<<endl;
                valid = true;
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)
y
2
Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)
Y
2
Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)
$
Invalid input.
Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)
n

Process returned 0 (0x0)
```

For uppercase n:

```
2
Would you like to perform other calculation?(Y/N)
N

Process returned 0 (0x0)
```

Comment: Don't use goto, really. It works, but don't. And why is valid set to true when its invalid?

Comment: And by the way, thanks ^^

Comment: I know is a bad practice code, I'll try improve the code. I was thinking to set the variable name valid into notValid, but then I ran out of time... x)